# Return a Map of words which can be formed by using other words which exist in the same list

Tags: string, dictionary, hashmap

Given a list of words return a Map of words which can be formed by using other words which exist in the same list.

```
 input = [“happy”, “rise”, “for”, “set”, “sunrise”, “su”, “nset”, “sunset”, “mind”, “happymind”, “n”, “rise”, “happysunrise”]

 output = {
  “happymind” : [[“happy”, “mind]],
  “sunrise” : [[“su”, “n”, “rise”], [“sun”, “rise”]],
  “sunset” : [[“sun”, “set”], [“su”, “n”, “set]],  
  “happysunrise” : [[“happy”, “sunrise”], [“happy”, “sun”, “rise”], [“happy”, “su”, “n”, 
   “rise”]]
 }
```

Comment: The word "sun" is absent in the given input list of words, then how is it present in the output map where keys are "sunrise", "sunset", and "happysunrise"?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Making trie of these words. But couldn't reach to the solution. Then i think of another solution by making a map of count of every word in dictionary.
Then For each word like "happy" find in dictionary by traversing each letter like

```
"happy"
"h" + "appy"
"ha" + "ppy"
"hap" + "py"
"happ" + "y"
```

But in this solution i am failing in those words which have a letter in between.Like

```
"sunrise" n is coming in between.
```